# layout_gravity isn't working as expected - just partially

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="@string/title_day"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="Tuesday"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_fail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+22"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this looks like this:

[image]

And I want the last TextView with id `tv_fail` to be pinned to right end of screen. I suppose that

```
android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
```

should handle it, but this instruction centers TextView vertically, but doesn't move it to end. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose that
>
> ```
> android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
> ```
>
> should handle it, but this instruction centers TextView vertically, but doesn't move it to end.

This is due to how `LinearLayout` works; your understanding of `layout_gravity` is generally correct.

LinearLayout takes its children and lays them out in a line, and the children will all be packed towards the "start" of the LinearLayout. In other words, a horizontal LinearLayout will ignore the horizontal component of the `layout_gravity` attribute of a child.

There are a few ways to work around this. The one that I think works best for your scenario is to make the TextView stretch to fill all the remaining space in the LinearLayout (using `layout_weight`), and then have the TextView position its text at the end of its content area (using `gravity`).

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_fail"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="+22"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="end"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! I did the same even without layout_weight, just with layout_width="match_parent" and gravity="end". But why does LinearLayout ignore layout_gravity?

Comment: `layout_gravity` is a sort of "general purpose" attribute that different ViewGroup subclasses interpret differently. LinearLayout already knows how to align its children along its primary axis (vertically or horizontally), so it ignores that component of the `layout_gravity` attribute. RelativeLayout and ConstraintLayout will ignore the attribute altogether! You'll just have to experiment to get used to how the attribute behaves for different parents, though once you've done it enough you'll get a general sense for what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

**If you just want to set `text` inside of your last `TextView` to end then you should use :**

```
android:gravity="end"
```

**for `TextView` gravity use:**

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

---

*Difference between `android:gravity` & `android:layout_gravity` is that first one arrange content inside of any view with given gravity while second one arranges view according to given gravity.*

---

> Updated code:
>
> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="horizontal">
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:orientation="vertical">
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:gravity="start"
>             android:text="title_day"
>             android:textSize="20sp"
>             android:textStyle="bold" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:gravity="start"
>             android:text="Tuesday"
>             android:textSize="16sp" />
>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/tv_fail"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="center"
>         android:text="+22"
>         android:textSize="16sp" />
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: No, I know this, but I want to set TextView widget to end of layout, not to set text inside of the last TextView to end.

Comment: Do you want it to be created by `LinearLayout` only? Try using `ConstraintLayout`. It is more flexible than this. Let me know if you want it to be created by `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: No, thanks, I know how to do it with ConstraintLayout, but it was my intent to create this layout namely with LinearLayout.